# paperclip + ActionMailer - Adding an attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, actionmailer

I have a paperclip'd file that I want to add as an attachment to my email....

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def XXXXXX_notification(record)
      @record = record

```
  attachments ??? How to add a paperclip file?

  mail( :to => "#{record.email}", 
        :subject => "XXXXXXXX"
        )
end
```

There seems to be nothing on the topic via google, if you have any ideas, I'd love to hear it :)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
  @comment.attachments.each do |a|
    tempfile = File.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.attachment_file_name}", "w")
    tempfile << open(a.authenticated_url())
    tempfile.puts
    attachments[a.attachment_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.attachment_file_name}")
    # Delete it tempfile
    #File.delete("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.filename}")
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Ruby on Rails guides (only reachable through [Bing](http://bing.com/)):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments

All that is left is to download the attachment (if in S3) to a [file](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) object or access it it is stored locally. Try using [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: thanks, but it's the opening of a paperclip file I can't figure out

Comment: So I need to download the S3 file and then read it?? I can't just access it and create the attachment?

Comment: Yes. You must have the file downloaded to attach it.

Comment: thanks. I'm trying that but no luck yet. I udpdated with the code any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It has been already answered but I just want to share a slightly different way to do it:

Here is my model Report. I'm using Paperclip.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :pdf_file
  ...
end
```

And here is my mailer ReportMailer

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def monthly_report_email(emails, report)
    attachments[report.pdf_file_file_name] = File.read(report.pdf_file.path)
    mail(:to => emails, :subject => 'monthly report')
  end
end
```