# Rails 3 ActionMailer sending 0 bytes pdf attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have managed to send an email with pdf attachments that are stored on s3

```
def welcome_pack1(website_registration)
      require 'open-uri'
      @website_registration = website_registration
      email_attachments = EmailAttachment.find(:all,:conditions=>{:goes_to_us=>true})

      email_attachments.each do |a|
        tempfile = File.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.pdf_file_name}", "w")
        tempfile << open(a.pdf.url)
        tempfile.puts
        attachments[a.pdf_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.pdf_file_name}")
      end

      mail(:to => website_registration.email, :subject => "Welcome")
  end
```

The attachments are attached to the email. But they come through as 0 bytes. I was using the example posted here [paperclip + ActionMailer - Adding an attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356936/paperclip-actionmailer-adding-an-attachment). Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

File objects are buffered - until you close the file (which you're not) then the bytes you've written may not be on disk. A great way to not forget to call close is to use the block form:

```
File.open(path, 'w') do |f|
  #do stuff to f
end #file closed for you when the block is exited.
```

I'm not sure why you're using a file at all though - why not do

```
attachments[a.pdf_file_name] = open(a.pdf.url)
```

Comment: Do file attachments in emails not have to be stored locally to be attached? Your second suggesting gives an error: undefined method `[]'

Comment: No - you can supply a file or you can just supply the data (which is what you were doing anyway, since you're calling File.read - action mailer doesn't know where the bytes came from). Don't know why you'd get that error without more info