# Rails PaperClip email attachment not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to email a PaperClip attachment. I've read several posts on StackExchange, but still can't get it to work. For some tries I get `undefined method'`, others take me to the login screen.

Comment Model:

```
  has_one :attachment
```

Mailer code I've tried:

```
attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(comment.attachment.to_file.path)

attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(comment.attachment.path)

attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(attachment_path(comment.attachment))
```

This is a copy of the browser console - I tried several things:

```
>> comment.attachment.attach_file_name
=> "2013-09-10_09-32-32.png"
>> comment.attachment.path
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for #  <Attachment:0x007f8d06903450>>
>> attachment_path(comment.attachment)
=> "/attachments/75"
>> File.read(attachment_path(comment.attachment))
!! #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /attachments/75>
>> File.read(attachment_path(comment.attachment).to_file)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_file' for  "/attachments/75":String>
>> File.read(comment.attachment.path)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for # <Attachment:0x007f8d06903450>>
>> File.read(comment.attachment.to_file.path)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_file' for # <Attachment:0x007f8d06903450>>
>>
```

So, this code:

```
attachment_path(comment.attachment)
```

Returns this:

```
"/attachments/75"
```

UDPATE

I tried this:

```
attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(comment.attachment.attach_url)
```

Got `undefined method attach_url`

So, tried these in the console:

```
>> comment.attachment.attach_url
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `attach_url' for # <Attachment:0x007f8d1c9b3cb8>>
>> attachment_path(comment.attachment)
=> "/attachments/76"
>> attachment_path(comment.attachment).attach_url
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `attach_url' for "/attachments/76":String>
>> attach_url(comment.attachment)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `attach_url' for #<CommentMailer:0x007f8d145664d8>>
>> attach_url_path(comment.attachment)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `attach_url_path' for # <CommentMailer:0x007f8d145664d8>>
>> attachment(comment.attachment)
!! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `attachment' for # <CommentMailer:0x007f8d145664d8>>
>>
```

Comment: That should be `comment.attachment.attach.url`

Comment: `comment.attachment.attach.path` should do the trick (url returns the relative path, and .path returns the full path of where the file is stored on your server(s))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sets up a one-to-one relationship between the `Comment` and the `Attachment` model:

```
has_one :attachment
```

This has nothing to do with Paperclip.

I assume that within your `Attachment` model you have something along the lines of the following:

```
has_attached_file :attach
```

You need to interact with the `:attach` attached to the `Attachment` model:

```
@comment.attachment.attach
```

When you're trying to attach this to your email you should be using something like this:

```
attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(comment.attachment.attach.path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  `has_attached_file :attach` Tried File.read(comment.attachment.attach.to_file.path). I get the following `undefined method `to_file' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007f8d22c88028>`

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `comment.attachment.attach.path` ... can you try that?

Comment: This worked: `attachments[comment.attachment.attach_file_name] = File.read(comment.attachment.attach.path)`

Comment: This works for local files. It doesn't work if your using Amazon S3 to store the attachments.  With S3, I get `No such file or directory - /attachments/attaches/000/000/085/original/2013-09-10_09-18-11.png`

Comment: You'd need to use `open-uri` to read the file via a URL. See this question/answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469796/trouble-adding-a-file-stored-on-s3-through-paperclip-as-an-attachment-in-actionm